# Do Solana blockchains have Chain IDs?

Tags: sol

Does Solana use Chain IDs the way they are used in EVM blockchains? I cannot find this in the Solana documentation and in the internet. If Solana uses Chain IDs, where can I find them? If not, is there a generally accepted way of distinguishing networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about different [clusters](https://docs.solana.com/clusters) which Solana maintains.

To fulfil different JSON-RPC requests to the same, endpoints are listed [here](https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints).

You can open a request to any of them by creating a connection and a provider.
In JavaScript, you can connect to the "devnet" cluster by doing the following :

```
import { clusterApiUrl , Connection } from "@solana/web3.js";
const networkUrl = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";   // RPC Endpoint
const connection = new Connection(networkUrl);
```